# Add a subrow on a GWT CellTable

Tags: gwt, celltable

I have a CellTable that needs a subrow of a different type; similar to http://showcase2.jlabanca-testing.appspot.com/#!CwCustomDataGrid

I do not want to use DataGrid as I understand it to have a fixed height, and my table looks better with a dynamic height.

I've tried to extend CellTable then write

```
    public void renderRowValues(SafeHtmlBuilder sb,
            java.util.List<ShipmentLeg> values,
            int start,
            SelectionModel<? super ShipmentLeg> selectionModel){
        super.renderRowValues(sb, values, start, selectionModel);

        GWT.log("HELLO");
    }
```

What is a good strategy to accomplish this?  Note: in this code GWT.log is never called as in the super a deprecation error is thrown

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API between `CellTable` and `DataGrid` is the same. As of GWT 2.5 the `renderRowValues()` method is deprecated hence, in order to alter the default table structure of both tables (say, creating subrows), you need to provide a `CellTableBuilder`.

Both table implementations use a `DefaultCellTableBuilder` (an extension of `AbstractCellTableBuilder` that leverage most of the bits and expose only a `buildRowImpl()` method). This is what you are looking for, no matter if you are using `CellTable` or `DataGrid`.

Extend `AbstractCellTableBuilder` and give an implementation of `buildRowImpl()`, much like the sample you linked, does. Do note that you linked an old sample. You should always refer to [the one](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid) in the current showcase, as the API is slightly different.

Side note: `DataGrid` does not have a 'fixed height' at all, but *requires* a `ProvidesResize` container, as it need to dynamically adjust its size when the layout change (e.g., on browser resize). Check [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#Resize) out, if you haven't already.